# Apache Mahout Vs Apache Spark in local mode with nutch data

Tags: apache-spark, solr, nutch, mahout, mahout-recommender

I already have nutch/solr application in single mode. I'm spouse to try integrating Mahout or spark to achieve kinda of personlized results. But I'm still a lot far from that point.

With lack of knowledge, time, and resources is there a fast and effective way to use one tool with Nutch's crawled.db or solr indexed data to represent personlization as a proof of concept?

I'm open to any idea.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are saying Spark vs Mahout- I think you are thinking of "old" MR based Mahout, which has been deprecated and moved to "community support".

I would recommend you use Mahout Samsara, which is a Spark library. E.g. my answer is you should use Mahout *and* Spark. For local mode though, you can just use Mahout Vectors / Matrices.

The question is vague, but based on the tags, I think this tutorial might be a good place to start, as it uses Mahout and Solr for a recommendation engine.

http://mahout.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/cco-lastfm/

Disclaimer: I'm a PMC of the Apache Mahout project.

Comment: I dont have the proper experience, it's a new field to me. My goal is to achieve personalization based on indexed data. Something with collaborative filtering or content filtering algorithm. The tool should be integrated to the whole system. But I'm not sure if my infrastructure is enough. So for this moment I need a visualizing how my results will look like.

Comment: OK- maybe check out Apache PredictionIO https://predictionio.apache.org

Comment: Is it possible to be deployed locally without integration?